# Android Auto NAVIGATE_INTENT Handling In Here Map shows no result.But works with google maps

Tags: android, here-api, android-auto

Need to navigate from my android auto app car screen to Here maps app with geo coordinates. With google maps and waze I am able to start navigation. But Here map showing no results found.

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(CarContext.ACTION_NAVIGATE)
                .setData(Uri.parse("geo:13.11978,+80.14994"));
            getCarContext().startCarApp(intent);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation#support-navigation-intents

Is this because Navigation Intent is not handled. Any other methods to route navigation to here maps in android auto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CarContext.ACTION_NAVIGATE)
        .setData(Uri.parse("geo=0,0?q=N Park St,+Secretariat Colony,+Venkatapuram,+Ambattur,+Chennai,+Tamil Nadu 600053,+India"));
getCarContext().startCarApp(intent);
```

Check format No. 2 in this documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/CarContext#startCarApp(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Will navigation based on coordinates be available any time soon.